# Who makes the Orange San Francisco phone?

Tags: zte-blade

Does anyone what company who makes [this phone](http://shop.orange.co.uk/mobile-phones/phones/phoneDetails.jsp?skuId=anySku&productId=prod2160151&_requestid=63190)? I assume it's made by a 'known' company but can't find any sign beyond the Orange branding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its original name was the *ZTE Blade* so, then, the manufacturer is the [ZTE](http://www.zte.com.cn/) corp in China.

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't heard of them until now but apparently they're very keen to expand into the US and Europe, starting with the UK.